# How to pass member function to SetConsoleCtrlHandler()?

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following code (sample) for a command line application.
I want to make sure, that Disconnect is called upon <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> Event.
That's why I added the Handler. 
Could I make CtrlHandler a member function, so that when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed, the handler has a valid `Foo` object to call `Disconnect()` on?

```
#include <windows.h> 

class Foo
{

 public :
     Foo()
     {
      Connect();
     }
     virtual ~Foo()
     {
       Disconnect();
     }

  protected:
     Run();
     Connect();
     Disconnect();
};

BOOL CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
    switch (fdwCtrlType)
    {
        // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        //Disconnect somehow
        return(TRUE);
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE );
  Foo myFoo;
  myFoo.Run();        
 }
```

Comment: No you can not make `CtrlHandler` a member function. A member function is not the same as a non-member function, member functions need an *instance* of a class to be called. The [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx) function simply have no way to provide an instance or other user-data. You could pass a `static` member function, or a capture-less lambda, to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, but that doesn't really help you with what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is to manage the callback's context yourself. A very simple approach in a single-threaded application, where `Run` cannot be re-entered.

```
#include <windows.h> 

class Foo
{

 public :
     Foo()
     {
      Connect();
     }
     virtual ~Foo()
     {
       Disconnect();
     }

  protected:
  static Foo* current_foo;
  static BOOL CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
  {
    switch (fdwCtrlType)
    {
        // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        current_foo->Disconnect();
        return(TRUE);
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
  }

     Run() {
       Foo::current_foo = this;
       SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE );
       // Other things
     }
     Connect();
     Disconnect();
};

Foo* Foo::current_foo = nullptr;    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Foo myFoo;
  myFoo.Run();        
}
```

Allow me to reiterate, however: you'll need something more robust for a less than trivial application.

Comment: But in your code `CtrlHandler` is a member of `Foo` if I'm not mistaken. So I can't call  `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` with a pointer to the member function?!

Comment: @biolightning It's a **static** member function. Those do not require an instance to be called. And can be used as callbacks to c APIs.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. But how do I pass `CtrlHandler` to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`? I get a `C2065 'CtrlHandler' undeclared identifier` compile error. And if I add the class's scope to it, I get `cannot access protected member declared in class 'Foo'`

Comment: @biolightning Whatever works for you. I usually try to expose as little in the public interface as possible.